# Can't get environment variable in linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I've got a .sh script and it has this "if" in it:

```
    if [ -z "$SOME_LIB" ]; then
    echo "Environment variable SOME_LIB is needed!"
    exit 1
    fi
```

Now. When I type "printenv" I can see that "SOME_LIB" has value "/usr/local/lib/python2.6
". That path is correct. And all is good.
But when I want to run that .sh file from terminal is gives me 
"Environment variable SOME_LIB is needed!"

What do i have to do to get it running properly?

Thank's for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Could you add `printenv` just befor the command `if` in the script?

It is possible that the variable is unset in the script before.

Another option, debug the script using `set -x` in it or running it using `bash -x`
to see what value contains the variable while checking.

Comment: But could you please add printenv just to check it?

Comment: Could you please start the script with `bash -x`?

Comment: @user3194248 - What Igor asks is that you add `printenv` as first line in your script, just before `if`. You could try this: `printenv | grep SOME_LIB; if ...` Then show the output. No need to display all the other env-variables.